# Why subtracting the addresses of consecutive values in the array gives different values, when stored and not stored in variables?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[2] = {1,3};
    long a0 = &a[0];
    long a1 = &a[1];
    printf("%ld - %ld = %d\n\n", &a[1], &a[0], ((&a[1]) - (&a[0]))); // prints 1
    printf("%ld - %ld = %d\n\n", a1, a0, a1 - a0); // prints 4
    printf("size of a0 [%ld] is %d\n", a0, sizeof(a0)); // prints [some number] and 8
    return 0;
}
```

I could not understand why it prints 1 instead of 4 in both print statements

In understood &a[1] gets next address of 1st byte in 2nd memory-block of 4 bytes.
Similarly &a[0] gets address of first byte in 1st memory-block of 4 bytes.
Storing into long data type and subtracting prints 4. But subtracting without storing gives 1. Could you please help me understand? Thank you!

Comment: Brush up on `pointer arithmetic`... (You're playing with fire, assigning memory addresses to `long` variables...)

Comment: You're using `%d` to format the difference between two pointers.  The difference between two pointers is defined to have type `ptrdiff_t`, which is a signed integer type but may not have the same size as an `int`.  If you want to use `%d`, then cast the argument to `int` before passing it.  So you very likely aren't printing what you think you're printing.  In the second `printf`, you're using `%d` to print the difference between two lons, which has type `long`, so you know that isn't right.  Always make your format specifiers and argument types match.

Comment: You got a few good answers.  Please make sure to accept the best one so we know you are all set.

Answer (score 1):

The type `long` is incompatible with the type of the expression `&a[0]` which is `int *`.  If you fix that problem the difference goes away:

```
    int *a0 = &a[0];
    int *a1 = &a[1];
```

When you subtract two pointers of an array you get number of elements of that type (no unit).  Another way of saying number of bytes divided by the `sizeof` the type.  When you subtract two long values you get the numerical difference (bytes unit).

Answer (score 1):

Three important things:

- `a[i]` is a shorthand for `*( a + i )`.
- An array treated as a pointer results in a pointer to its first element.
- Adding to a pointer advanced the pointer by that many elements, not bytes.

---

Given the above equivalent, for `a[i]` to work, `a + i` must not add `i` to the address but `i * sizeof(*a)`. And so it is defined.

```c
uint64_t a[2];

// Pointer to the array.
printf( "%p\n", (void*)( &a      ) );  // 0x1000   Type: uint64_t(*)[2]

// Pointers to the first element.
printf( "%p\n", (void*)( a       ) );  // 0x1000   Type: uint64_t*
printf( "%p\n", (void*)( &a[0]   ) );  // 0x1000   Type: uint64_t*
printf( "%p\n", (void*)( &*(a+0) ) );  // 0x1000   Type: uint64_t*
printf( "%p\n", (void*)( a+0     ) );  // 0x1000   Type: uint64_t*
printf( "%p\n", (void*)( &a[0]+0 ) );  // 0x1000   Type: uint64_t*

// Pointers to the second element.
printf( "%p\n", (void*)( &a[1]   ) );  // 0x1008   Type: uint64_t*
printf( "%p\n", (void*)( &*(a+1) ) );  // 0x1008   Type: uint64_t*
printf( "%p\n", (void*)( a+1     ) );  // 0x1008   Type: uint64_t*
printf( "%p\n", (void*)( &a[0]+1 ) );  // 0x1008   Type: uint64_t*
```

---

What about `&a[1] - &a[0]`?

If `x + 1 = y`, then `y - x = 1`.
We know that `&a[0] + 1` is `&a[1]`, so `&a[1] - &a[0]` must be `1`.
This must be the case even if the pointers represent addresses 8 byte apart.

```c
   &a[1] - &a[0]
=  &( *( a + 1 ) ) - &( *( a + 0 ) )
=  ( a + 1 ) - ( a + 0 )               // &* "cancels out"
=  1
```

Notice how the type of `a[0]` doesn't come into play.

Comment: Your example at the end makes intuitive sense (and the result is correct), but is pointer arithmetic really associative and commutative? So, are you formally allowed to remove the parentheses and reorder `( a + 1 ) - ( a + 0 )` to `a - a + 1 - 0`? Is that defined somewhere in the standard? As seen from the question, "simple intuitive arithmetic" is not always correct when dealing with pointers and addresses.

Comment: @Fritz `+` does addition. And therefore has the properties of addition. But this being computers, overflows, underflows and loss of precision can muck things up. (Floating point operations are specifically quite sensitive to reordering.) But since we're talking about pointers into one object, that's not an issue here. (Arithmetic on pointers to different objects is undefined.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that an address can fit into a `long`:

---

`&a[0]` - type is a pointer to int
`&a[1]` - type is a pointer to int

the distance between `&a[0]` and `&a[1]` is `1` element (`int`).

The compiler knows at compile time the size in bytes of a type on the target system. Therefore, if you initialize an array, the consecutive values will be stored `sizeof(type)` bytes apart. The value `1` in your example, simply mirrors the fact, that the values (and the addresses thereof) are `1 * sizeof(type)` bytes apart.

---

`a0` and `a1` are both of type `long` and do store the address values of `a[0]` and `a[1]`, from above we know that they are `1` (`int`) element apart, therefore the difference between `a0` and `a1` is the size in bytes of `int` (which happens to be `4` on your system).

(for now, we don't need to mention alignment and padding).

---

If you print `a0` then you print the value of the address of `a[0]` (which indeed is some arbitrary number).

Should be the same output as `printf("%p", &a[0])`.

The `sizeof` operator returns the number of bytes of the type or expression, see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof. In this case it prints the size of the type of `a0` which is a `long` and that happens to be `8` bytes wide on your system.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to know how many bit computer that you used, 32-bit or 64-bit.

Use 32-bit or 64-bit will get different result. According to your output:

```
sizeof(a0) == 8  // long a0  //64-bit computer
```

we can know you use 64-bit computer. But the reverse isn't true. Because `long` is 4 bytes in 64-bit Windows system.

If you use 32-bit computer or 64-bit Windows system:

```
sizeof(a0) == 4  // long a0  //32-bit computer or 64-bit Windows system
```

Below is my .c file:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[2] = {1,3};
    long a0 = &a[0];    // don't suggest
    long a1 = &a[1];    // don't suggest

    int* p1 = &a[0];    // correct 
    int* p2 = &a[1];    // correct

    printf("%ld - %ld = %d\n\n", &a[1], &a[0], ((&a[1]) - (&a[0]))); // prints 1
    printf("%ld - %ld = %d\n\n", a1, a0, a1 - a0);  //prints 4
    printf("size of a0 [%ld] is %ld\n", a0, sizeof(a0));  //prints [some number] and 8

    printf("size of p1 [%p] is %d\n", p1, sizeof(p1)); 
    printf("%p - %p = %d\n", p2, p1, p2-p1);
    return 0;
}
```

Run it will output(on 64-bit computer):

```
140727877619764 - 140727877619760 = 1

140727877619764 - 140727877619760 = 4

size of a0 [140727877619760] is 8
size of p1 [0x7ffdc327d030] is 8
0x7ffdc327d034 - 0x7ffdc327d030 = 1
```

## Explain:

#### Important note: type of value of &a[0] is `int*`, type of value of &a[1] also is `int*`, on 64-bit computer and 32-bit computer sizeof(int) is almost always equal to 4.

so in my code you see:

```
int* p1 = &a[0];
int* p2 = &a[1];
```

type of value of p2 - p1 is `int`, p2 - p1 = ((&a[1]) - (&a[0])) / sizeof(int) = ((&a[1]) - (&a[0])) / 4

(&a[1]) - (&a[0]) refers to pointer arithmetic that need to be divided by sizeof(a[0]), but a1 - a0 just type of two long subtract that like 5 - 3 = 2.

That's reason why print different of (&a[1]) - (&a[0])) and a1 - a0

Comment: *According to your output:

`sizeof(a0) == 8  // long a0  //64-bit`

we can know you use 64-bit computer.*  But the reverse isn't true.  `long` is 4 bytes in 64-bit Windows.  So *If you use 32-bit computer:

`sizeof(a0) == 4  // long a0  //32-bit`* will also apply to 64-bit Windows.  Mostly because Windows was slow to 64 bits and the `long long` type was standard by then.  64-bit Unix systems predate C99 with its 64-bit `long long` so the only way pre-C99 systems could standardize a 64-bit type was to make `long` 64 bits.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I see `long` is 8 bytes on 64-bit computer  at `chapter 2.1.2 Data sizes`  book named `computer  system a programmer's perspective(third edition)`

Comment: At best, that book is incomplete.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models  Note that Windows uses the `LLP64` data model - `long long` and pointers are 64 bits.  `long` and `int` are 32-bit.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thank you for your explain, I changed my answer.