# strange behaviour with pointer arithmetics in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, pointer-arithmetic

Please can someone explain to me this strange pointer behaviour. Did I miss something?!?

start first attempt

```
int *foo=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*4);//allocates memory for 4 integer with size of sizeof(int) foo points to the address of the first element-  foo=&foo[0]

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    *foo=i+1;
    foo++;
    printf("foo[%d] :%d \n",i,foo[i]);
}
```

Otput is something like this

```
foo[0] :0
foo[1] :0
foo[2] :0
foo[3] :0
```

end first attempt

Lets add one tiny thing to our code:

start second attempt

```
int *foo=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*4);//same as first attempt

int* ptr=foo;//???????????????????? why this is necessary?

printf("Value of foo: %d value of ptr is: %d &foo[0] %d\n",foo,ptr, &foo[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    *ptr=i+1;//assign and update via ptr
    ptr++;
    printf("foo[%d] :%d \n",i,foo[i]);
}
```

Output

```
Value of foo: 1322628816 value of ptr is: 1322628816 &foo[0] 1322628816
foo[0] :1
foo[1] :2
foo[2] :3
foo[3] :4
```

end second attempt

Note: I use Ubuntu 18.04, gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-2ubuntu1\~18.04) 11.4.0 with GNU C Library (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1.6) stable release version 2.27

I try exactly what I wrote above

Comment: Please repost your code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: `foo++;` - In 1, you change foo so foo[0] no longer points to the first int in your buffer.  It points to buffer[1]. buffer[2]. buffer[3]. buffer[ OVERRUN ]

Comment: Please post the *complete* code, a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest code that users can copy/paste and compile exactly as-is.

Comment: Note: Use `%p` to print pointer values. Strictly speaking, the pointer value being printed should be of type `void *` so you need to type-cast the pointer arguments being printed in the `printf` call like this: `printf("Value of foo: %p value of ptr is: %p &foo[0] %p\n",(void*)foo,(void*)ptr, (void*)&foo[0]);`.

Answer (score 4):

After you do `foo++`, `foo` no longer points to the beginning of the array, it points the `i+1`th element of the array. When you then try to access `foo[i]`, you're accessing the element `i` places *after* this element, i.e. `original_foo[i+1+i]`.

It works in the second version because the pointer you're indexing is not the one you're incrementing. So `foo` continues to point to the beginning of the array, and `foo[i]` is the element you just assigned.

Answer (score 4):

```
*foo=i+1;
```

This initializes the first `int` of the four-`int` area you `malloc()`ed.

```
foo++;
```

This makes `foo` point to the *second* `int`.

```
printf("foo[%d] :%d \n",i,foo[i]);
```

You're printing `foo + i`, i.e. the *second* (uninitialized) `int`, invoking UB.

Things get only worse from there. The second iteration of your loop (with `i == 1`)...

```
*foo=i+1;
```

`foo` still points to the *second* `int`, so you write `1` there...

```
foo++;
```

`foo` now points to the *third* `int`...

```
printf("foo[%d] :%d \n",i,foo[i]);
```

...and you print `foo + i`, that is the third `int` plus `1` -- the *fourth* `int`, which again is uninitialized (again, undefined behavior).

In the third and fourth iteration of your loop, you end up reading from memory you haven't even `malloc()`ed.

---

Your second example works since you increment `ptr` for writing, and `i` (as index on `foo`) for reading. As you no longer double-increment, that second example works.

The correct solution for your first example, of course, would be to use `foo[i]` consistently and *not increment `foo`*.

Answer (score 3):

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    *foo=i+1;                           // 1
    foo++;                              // 2
    printf("foo[%d] :%d \n",i,foo[i]);  // 3
}
```

1. Here you assign `i+1` to the `int` `foo` points at. That in itself is not wrong.
2. Here you make `foo` point at the next element in the allocated memory. You've now lost the base pointer - unless you later restore it by counting backwards or saving the pointer before the loop starts.
3. In `foo[i]` you add yet `i` to where the base pointer points. You've now effectively made it `*(original_foo + i + i)` which very soon becomes out of bounds.

An idiomatic solution would be to *not* change `foo` at all:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    foo[i] = i + 1;
    printf("foo[%d] :%d \n", i, foo[i]);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jcGWdPT9s)

Regarding:

> `int* ptr=foo;//???????????????????? why this is necessary?`

That's the saving of the base pointer I mentioned as a possible workaround in point 2 above. In the following loop, you only change `ptr` and let the base pointer `foo` be untouched. Dereferencing `foo[i]` (same as `*(foo + i)`) then does the correct thing.

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    *ptr=i+1;                          // 1
    ptr++;                             // 2
    printf("foo[%d] :%d \n",i,foo[i]); // 3
}
```

1. Again, assign `i+1` to where `ptr` points.
2. Step the temporary `int*` one step ahead.
3. Dereference `foo[i]` (`*(foo + i)`) which dereferences the same address that `ptr` pointed at prior to `ptr++`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's at first consider the first code snippet

```
int *foo=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*4);//allocates memory for 4 integer with size of sizeof(int) foo points to the address of the first element-  foo=&foo[0]

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    *foo=i+1;
    foo++;
    printf("foo[%d] :%d \n",i,foo[i]);
}
```

Firstly you allocated an array for 4 objects of the type `int` using the function `malloc`

```
int *foo=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*4);//allocates memory for 4 integer with size of sizeof(int) foo points to the address of the first element-  foo=&foo[0]
```

The allocated memory is uninitialized. It can contain all zeroes or some random values. That is the memory contains indeterminate values.

In the for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    *foo=i+1;
    foo++;
    printf("foo[%d] :%d \n",i,foo[i]);
}
```

you are assigning values `i + 1` to each object

```
*foo=i+1;
```

but then you are increasing the pointer

```
foo++;
```

and moreover using the pointer arithmetic `foo[i]`  are trying to output values that even are not stored in the allocated memory.

As a result there is an access to uninitialized memory and  even outside the allocated memory. So this call of `printf`

```
printf("foo[%d] :%d \n",i,foo[i]);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

How to change the for loop to output valid values?

Just do not increase the pointer. That is write

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    foo[i] = i+1;
    printf("foo[%d] :%d \n",i,foo[i]);
}
```

In this case the pointer `foo` will still have the address of the extent of the allocated memory and you can free the allocated memory after the loop like

```
free( foo );
```

It just occured such a way that the memory you are accessing contains zeroes. However in general the output can differ from that

```
foo[0] :0
foo[1] :0
foo[2] :0
foo[3] :0
```

and can display any random values.

In the for loop of the second code snippet

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    *ptr=i+1;//assign and update via ptr
    ptr++;
    printf("foo[%d] :%d \n",i,foo[i]);
}
```

the expressions *ptr and `foo[i]` are equivalent.

`i` means the `i-th`  element of the array. If for example `i` was equal to `0` then `*ptr` and `foo[0]` yeilds the same element. When `i` was increased then the expression `foo[1]` is evaluated like `*( foo + 1 )`.  But it is the same as `ptr++` and then using `*ptr` because after `ptr++` `ptr`  is equal to `ptr + 1`. In other words the expression `foo[1]` that is the same as `*( foo + 1 )` can be represented like `*( ( ptr = ptr + 1 ) )` or like an expression with the comma operator `*( ptr++, ptr )`.

From the C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
> is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
> definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
> (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
> binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
> to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
> E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

Answer (score 0):

This is not strange behaviour.

First attempt approach is wrong. Correct approach is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    //allocates memory for 4 integer with size of sizeof(int) foo points 
    //to the address of the first element-  foo=&foo[0]
    int *foo=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*4);

    if(foo == NULL){
        printf("malloc memory failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    memset(foo, 0, sizeof(int)*4);
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        printf("foo[%d] address is %p\n", j, &foo[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
            foo[i]=i+1;
            printf("foo[%d] :%d \n",i,foo[i]);
    }
    free(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Run it will output:

```
foo[0] address is 0x5635caaac2a0
foo[1] address is 0x5635caaac2a4
foo[2] address is 0x5635caaac2a8
foo[3] address is 0x5635caaac2ac

foo[0] :1 
foo[1] :2 
foo[2] :3 
foo[3] :4
```

Second attempt is correct:

```
int* ptr=foo;//???????????????????? why this is necessary?
```

type of value of ptr is `int*`, value of address of ptr is `&foo[0]`, so when `ptr + 1` is equal to `value of address of ptr + sizeof(int) = &foo[0] + 4`.

When you `int *foo=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*4);`, you can see `foo` as `int foo[4]`, about array see more details at [Why subtracting the addresses of consecutive values in the array gives different values, when stored and not stored in variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77004351/why-subtracting-the-addresses-of-consecutive-values-in-the-array-gives-different/77004732#77004732)